# What are the advantages and dis-advantages of different kinds of FSM encoding techniques?

Tags: verilog

What are the advantages and dis-advantages of Binary, Gray & one hot encoding techniques for FSM encoding in verilog ? What are the different applications of these encoding techniques in hardware, where are they used ?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question can be easily find [here](http://www.edaboard.com/thread102911.html) or [here](http://www.vlsi-world.com/content/view/42/34/). To sum this articles up:

- Binary Encoding (e.g. `00`, `01`, `10`, `11`):

  - default encoding type (that's why it's very popular),  implements very less logic.
- One-hot encoding (e.g. `1000`, `0100`, `0010`, `0001`):

  - allows to create "faster" state machines, 'cause you don't need to decode state. However, it uses one flip-flop for each state.
- Gray Encoding (e.g. `00`, `01`, `11`, `10`):

  - it's very useful when the outputs of the state bits are used asynchronously, because it avoids intermediate logics. Hamming distance between two states is equal to 1, so this encoding method is very reliable.

PS You might also find [State Machine Design Techniques
for Verilog and VHDL](http://s.eeweb.com/pl/1276365773-FSM-Verilog-VHDL.pdf) very useful.